# handling external libraries and name hashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, gulp, bower

let's say we want to use existing libraries (like bootstrap). for testing it's faster to use local version. for production, it would be nice to use CDN version with a fallback to the local one. also the local one should have distinct name: not bootstrap.min.js (the default name made by bower) but something like bootstrap-3.2.0.min.js (or with hash). is there any grunt or gulp plugin that handles all of that automatically?

Comment: https://github.com/callumlocke/grunt-cdnify

Answer (score 0):

have you tried scaffolding tools such as [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) ?

that will let you handle your packages and any dependencies.